# CoC Python reports unresolved import in git subfolder

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc

I have a Python project in a subfolder within my git repo:

```
.git
api/
  requirements.txt
  .venv/
  myproj/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
    bar.py
```

The virtual environment is installed in the `api` folder which is a subfolder of my git repo.

In an interpreter, I can import from `myproj/foo.py` by doing:

```
from myproj.foo import baz
```

But in Vim, coc-python reports:

```
unresolved import myproj.foo
```

and the autocompletion list includes the parent directory, `api`!

```
api.myproj.foo
api.myproj.bar
```

When I do `:CocCommand > python.startREPL` I can run the import just fine, without prepending `api`.

I can't even think about how to debug this problem!

Any pointers?

Comment: I think I've found my answer: https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki/Using-workspaceFolders

Comment: If you have a solution, please write it up in an answer for future readers!

Answer (score 2):

CoC assumes that a directory containing `.git/` is the root of your project.

According to the [CoC docs](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki/Using-workspaceFolders#resolve-workspace-folder):

> Unlike VSCode vim doesn't have workspace support. The solution is resolve workspace folders from opened files.

This means that CoC uses a list of filenames which, if present in a particular directory, indicate that it might be the project's root.

If the variable is not present, CoC falls back to a config setting called `coc.preferences.rootPatterns` which, by default is:

```
[".git", ".hg", ".projections.json"]
```

To override this behaviour you can set the list to include the name of your virtual environment. In this case:

```
autocmd FileType python let b:coc_root_patterns = ['.git', '.venv']
```